# Solve cross join using date

Tags: sql, oracle12c

I have 3 tables:

```
Client (cus_id, First_Name)
sms_Log (sms_log_id, cus_id, sms_time)
Mail_Log (mail_Log_id, cus_id, mailed_time)
```

Cus_id is the link between three tables, however, there is no link between sms_log and Mail_Log which results in a cross join. I need to group all sms received after a mail was sent.

E.g. Data

```
Table: Client
cus_id  First_Name
4       'Doe'

Table: sms_log
sms_log_id  cus_id, sms_time
1           4       08/02/2012
2           4       08/03/2012
3           4       08/06/2012

Table: Mail_Log
mail_Log_id cus_id  mailed_time
1           4       08/01/2012
2           4       08/05/2012
```

Joining these would create a cross join with 6 records.

Is there a way I could write a query that can tell me that the first two SMS (dates 2 & 3) were received in response to mail on 01 and the SMS on day 06 was in response to mail sent on 05?

Expected output (count of sms received for each mail)

```
Table: output_record
cus_id  mail_Log_id, sms_received
4       1            2
4       2            1
```

Comment: which database system are you using ? Please choose appropirately

Comment: I think, here the sms_log_id  and mail_Log_id  should be incremental data not to be same

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Comment: @Mittal - Yes, sorry for the mistake, i edited the question to reflect that

Comment: Can you please share the expected output in table format for more clarity

Comment: @Mittal - Thank you, I updated the question with sample output

Comment: What version of Oracle? (As reported if you run `select * from v$version`.) There are several solutions possible; in Oracle 12.1 and above, `match_recognize` can do quick work of this task.

Comment: @mathguy - Thanks for the reply, I am on mentioned version.
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production

Could you please help me frame the logic using match_recognize?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Oracle 12.1 and above you can solve this with the `match_recognize` clause.

Of the three tables you described, you don't need the first one for "the problem at hand". You can join the result of the query below to the `customer` table, if you need to retrieve client name and other particulars; I will assume you are able to do that yourself.

Then, to get the summary you need from the inputs in the other two tables, you do NOT need a join at all. You need a UNION ALL (done carefully), and then you can use nested analytic functions (in earlier versions of Oracle) or do all the work in a single pass with `match_recognize`, as shown below.

In a `WITH` clause, I create the test data since you didn't provide it. Please note that the `WITH` clause is not part of the solution - you should remove it, and in the rest of the query make sure the table and column names match your actual inputs.

The middle section is the `union all` of (the relevant columns from) the two log tables. Then the `match_recognize` is at the end. It produces one row for each complete match found - where a "match" consists of a single mail event followed by all the ensuing SMS events until the next mail event. Everything is partitioned by `cus_id` first (as needed), and each such partition by `cus_id` is ordered by event time (either mailed time or sms time). I allowed also for the possibility that a mail and an sms are logged at exactly the same time (very rare occurrence, but not impossible). In such cases I will assume the mail was sent first, so the sms belongs to that mail (not to the previous one). This can be changed easily, if needed.

```
with
  sms_log ( sms_log_id, cus_id, sms_time ) as (
    select 1, 4, to_date('08/02/2012', 'mm/dd/yyyy') from dual union all
    select 2, 4, to_date('08/03/2012', 'mm/dd/yyyy') from dual union all
    select 3, 4, to_date('08/06/2012', 'mm/dd/yyyy') from dual
  ),
  mail_log ( mail_Log_id, cus_id, mailed_time ) as (
    select 1, 4, to_date('08/01/2012', 'mm/dd/yyyy') from dual union all
    select 2, 4, to_date('08/05/2012', 'mm/dd/yyyy') from dual
  )
select cus_id, mail_log_id, sms_received
from (
       select cus_id, mail_log_id, mailed_time as tm
         from mail_log
       union all
       select cus_id, null, sms_time
         from sms_log
     )
match_recognize(
  partition by cus_id
  order by     tm, mail_log_id
  measures     m.mail_log_id as mail_log_id,
               m.tm          as mailed_time,
               count(*) - 1  as sms_received
  pattern      ( m s* )
  define       m as mail_log_id is not null,
               s as mail_log_id is null
)
order by cus_id, mailed_time
;

CUS_ID MAIL_LOG_ID SMS_RECEIVED
------ ----------- ------------
     4           1            2
     4           2            1
```

Comment: Thansk for the query so far, there is just one change that is needed to match the desired output. Instead of a count of 3, the first line should show output of 2 and the second line (mail_log_id = 2) should have sms received as 1.  
Is there a way to tweak this query to achieve that?

Comment: @KRAM - Oh, I missed that.... you just want the count of SMS's and I calculated the count including the mail (email) that initiated the cycle. It's easy to fix: just subtract 1 from the COUNT(*) in the MEASURES clause. I will edit the Answer to fix that.

Comment: Thanks a ton! really appreciate your help.